# How to access Backbone.Model methods from Marionette.js ItemView template?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I'm trying to access a model's method from within an .eco template using backbone/marionette.js. I have an `Expense` model with a `day()` method which, using moment.js, returns '13th'; for example:

```coffee
class Expense extends Backbone.Model
  day: ->
    moment.get('date').format('Do')
```

I can create a new `Expense` as follows, and call the `day()` method:

```coffee
coffee = new Expense({name: "Coffee", amount: 2.50, date: "2014-01-13T13:50:00Z"})
coffee.day() # 13th
```

However, trying to access `day()` from within the following view and template is causing me some problems:

```coffee
class ExpenseView extends Marionette.ItemView
  template: "views/_expense"
```

```ruby
# views/_expense.jst.eco
<h3 class="expense__name"><%= @name %></h3>
<p class="expense__day"><%= @day() %></p>
```

I *understand* why it isn't working...the `ItemView` calls `serializeData` which returns `@model.toJSON()`... therefore, the `Expense`'s `day()` method isn't accessible. Is there an established pattern in the backbone/marionette community that makes model methods available to templates?

So far, I've done the following to make it work:

```coffee
class ExpenseView extends Marionette.ItemView
  template: "views/_expense"

  serializeData: ->
    _.extend(@model.toJSON(), model: @model)

  templateHelpers:
    day: ->
      @model.day()
```

But I'm unsure whether this is the best way to go about the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always add it to `templateHelpers` or `serializeData` - but what you're really asking about is a virtual attribute - one that can be part of every template, an attribute that is used solely as part of a `ViewModel`.  In this way we can also disable it from syncing to the server on `sync` events such as `save()`

There are several plugins out there that do this, my personal favorite to use is `Backbone Mutators` - https://github.com/asciidisco/Backbone.Mutators

Others like `Backbone Computed Fields` - https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/backbone-computedfields give you Ember like computed properties.

With Backbone Mutators you would write your mutators in the Backbone Model.

```
class Model extends Backbone.Model
  mutators:
    day: ->
      moment.get('date').format('Do')
```

Alternatively to prevent the 'day' attribute from syncing to the backend...

```
class Model extends Backbone.Model
  mutators:
    day:
      get: -> moment.get('date').format('Do')
      transient: true
```

The `day` attribute will be present in all `toJSON()` calls now.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I quite like this Backbone.Mutators plugin! I like how it moves the logic out of my views and into the model – a bit like :scope in rails. The `transient: true` is a nice addition too!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add it to `serializeData` ? (Can't remember Coffee syntax...)

```
serializeData: function(){
    var data = _.clone(this.model.attributes);
    data.day = this.model.day();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, I was thinking maybe it'd just be better to override `Expense`'s `toJSON` method instead...that way the logic is encapsulated in the model rather than the view?

Comment: The rpoblem is that if you add it to `toJSON` it will get sent to the API endpoint also, which might be an issue.

Comment: Ahh I see. Maybe I could extend `serializeData` in all `Marionette.View`s such that it would call a new method `toData` (or a better name) if it existed, else just call `toJSON` as normal. Then I could optionally implement `toData` in any of my models to merge the models attributes with any custom ones I choose?

Comment: That's a possibility. Or define an `extendJSON` method with the extra params you wan to add. Then in Marionette's `serailzeData` you simply `_.extend` the normal value that gets returned (if `extendJSON` is defined) by adding the result of `extendJSON`. This would avoid code duplication.